# Как управлять множеством бото при помощи одного?

Tags: python, telebot

У меня есть 5 серверов, на которых запущен определенный код, на каждом сервере он идентичен, единственное, что токен различны, каждым из серверов я могу управлять при помощи Telegram бота.

Возможно ли как то реализовать управление не отдельно каждым ботом, а запихнуть эти

Comment: через чат например? Что вы подразумеваете под управлением? Можно написать у 5ти ботов, например, функции для их общей конфигурации. Добавить их всех в чат, и они будут реагировать на одну и ту же команду. Простой пример: по команде /sum мы будем складывать 5 + 5, пропишем это у каждого бота, добавим их в общий чат, напишем команду /sum и получим 5 ответов. Таким же образом можно конфигурировать их сразу, при помощи заранее прописанного кода. Вы можете написать отдельную библиотеку(файл кода) на который будут ссылаться все 5 ботов, в котором как раз и будет логика управления.